# Route Windows 8 sound to DLNA device

Tags: audio, dlna, upnp

Is that possible? Maybe some drivers exist that add DLNA device as Windows sound card? One possibility that I found:

http://www.dbpoweramp.com/asset-upnp-dlna.htm

It says: PC Sound Card Streaming

But it is in payed version only and I don't know how good it is at this. Does anyone know alternatives, maybe free per chance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried [Stream What You Hear](http://www.streamwhatyouhear.com/) with OpenELEC as the audio target and it worked out-of-the-box. AFAICS it's not implemented as a sound card device, but it seems to do the trick:

> Stream What You Hear (SWYH) is a Windows application to broadcast the
>   sound of your computer (ie: “what you hear”) on an UPnP/DLNA device
>   such as TVs, amps, network receivers, game consoles, etc…

(from the [About](http://www.streamwhatyouhear.com/about/) page)

And it's free :-)

Comment: This probably works by capturing sound output using WASAPI. Just pass sound through your regular output device and it’ll do its magic. Way better because it doesn’t require drivers or anything.

Comment: Another daemon running on machine is way worse than having driver and running from the kernel. But this is feasible if there is no more mature solution.

Comment: I confirm that latest version of SWYH works but with lag 3-5 seconds (PCM) or 15-17 seconds (MP3). SWYH version 1.4. Of course, 3-5 seconds is very bad result. I'm quite distressed with all this unfriendly DLNA thing. It always doesn't work well. But as an answer this is acceptable...

Comment: Indeed, the lag really sucks :-/

Comment: I must add that last version 1.4 is badly written: CPU leak 100% after long run. Therefore this program is unusable.

Comment: It doesn't work on windows 10 (at least v1.4.16069)

Answer (score 4):

Jamcast does PC desktop audio to DLNA devices and has a free version with 30 minute time limit so you can try before you buy.

http://getjamcast.com

I use this to play Spotify to my Samsung HDTV and now also my Xbox One.

Comment: Does not work on Windows 10 : no sound / decoding errors on remote device

Answer (score 0):

TuneBlade is another solution.

http://www.tuneblade.com/

However, I cannot make it work on Windows 10, failing to initialize audio capture.

Answer (score 0):

Mar 21 update: TuneBlade casts to devices which emulate the Apple AirPlay; Stream What You Hear (SWYH) casts to DLNA devices. As far as I know Windows 10 uses LPCM for DLNA. I have an Arylic S50 WiFi receiver which supports both AirPlay and DLNA but (small print) doesn't support LPCM, only WAV and MP3. So TuneBlade works for me on Windows, but SWYH doesn't. (With all software as of March 2021, Win10/64.) Both TuneBlade and SWYH stream ALL Windows audio, including system sounds. Foobar2000 can be set up (with a plugin) to cast to the S50; I'm not sure if via AirPlay or DLNA.
HTH